# How Can I use NativeBase Sketch Template and install it?

Tags: android, react-native, native-base

somebody show me how can i use NativeBase Sketch Template.
Link:
https://nativebase.io/sketch-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the [ReadMe](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-Sketch-Template/blob/master/README.md) of [NativeBase-Sketch-Template](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-Sketch-Template) for installation and configuration.

You need to have Sketch application installed on your system, in order to use NativeBase Sketch Template